# Ethereum block time assessment

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, openethereum

Solana docs say:

> In Proof of Work consensus, these block times need to be very large
> (~10 minutes) to minimize the odds of multiple validators producing a
> new valid block at the same time. There's no such constraint in Proof
> of Stake consensus, but without reliable timestamps, a validator
> cannot determine the order of incoming blocks. The popular workaround
> is to tag each block with a wallclock timestamp. Because of clock
> drift and variance in network latencies, the timestamp is only
> accurate within an hour or two. To workaround the workaround, these
> systems lengthen block times to provide reasonable certainty that the
> median timestamp on each block is always increasing.

Solana docs say:

My assessment:

Let's quickly discuss Ethereum's proof of work. Block time is so small(3sec).In such case, multiple blocks can be solved at the same time, if so, one of the blocks will be discarded and another one will be added. Now, chance is nodes don't know which block they should add to their chain, but I guess, whichever gets propagated first to them, they add that. So, in the nutshell, that's a problem because even though 2 blocks were mined at the same time, there would still be `milliseconds` difference when they were solved, but since time can't be trusted this much, node that receives such 2 blocks can't decide which one to add to the chain, so adds the one that was very first received(it could have received a block - `blockA` that was solved after `blockB`, but still received `blockA` due to network propagation). And that's what Solana calls a problem as it's a little bit unfair.

**Q1: Am I right what I assessed and what Solana describes as a problem above ?**

**Q2: From the paragraph I copied/pasted above, It mentions this:**

> Because of clock drift and variance in network latencies, the
> timestamp is only accurate within an hour or two.

Why does it say `an hour or two` ? ethereum doesn't let adding blocks that are more than 10sec difference from the local time of receiver's block. Any idea ?

Comment: "Because of clock drift and variance in network latencies, the timestamp is only accurate within an hour or two." I do not know what sources you are reading, but they are completely bullshit. Stop reading garbage.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa its here https://docs.solana.com/cluster/synchronization . WDYT ?

Comment: Still garbage. I suggest you open a bug in Solana issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's quickly discuss Ethereum's proof of work. Block time is so
> small(3sec).In such case, multiple blocks can be solved at the same
> time, if so, one of the blocks will be discarded and another one will
> be added. Now, chance is nodes don't know which block they should add
> to their chain, but I guess, whichever gets propagated first to them,
> they add that. So, in the nutshell, that's a problem because even
> though 2 blocks were mined at the same time, there would still be
> milliseconds difference when they were solved, but since time can't be
> trusted this much, node that receives such 2 blocks can't decide which
> one to add to the chain, so adds the one that was very first
> received(it could have received a block - blockA that was solved after
> blockB, but still received blockA due to network propagation). And
> that's what Solana calls a problem as it's a little bit unfair.

The [target block time](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ae5fcdc67fbfa208de257487cb86271b429545df/consensus/ethash/difficulty.go#L30) in Ethereum is 13 seconds, I suppose that was a typo. I understand that one may consider such situation unfair **if you know the true orderering of the blocks creation in your time frame**. But no one does, as you said "time cannot be trusted". In such a situation (and assuming that both block lead to equal total difficulty and have roughly equal timestamps), there is not way of taking a "fair" decision, since you cannot accept any timestamp proof as valid, and you cannot rely on the order of reception neither due to network instability.

An interesting point, is that such decisions (pick first / pick last) can actually be used against the PoW network to conduct selfish mining attacks since it gives indication on which branch will be picked, the current selection rule for both Bitcoin and Ethereum is 50% chance for each block in case of same height / same difficulty competing blocks as you can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6ce4670bc03602bb6638c490f892e848647c15c0/core/forkchoice.go#L104) (If you are curious, this is explained in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0243.pdf)).

And while this solution was not intended to solve the fairness problem you are describing (it it first of all a mitigation mechanism against selfish mining), I could easily argue that when nothing can be proved / disproved with certainty, a 50 / 50 seems like the most fair decision you could make.

> Q1: Am I right what I assessed and what Solana describes as a problem
> above ?

The problem that they are really talking about is not really about fairness, it's just about fork probability in PoW blockchains. This probability is basically linked to the block rate and block size (the larger the block the longer the propagation time). When you mix such probability with a lousy definition of time you get into situations where conflicting blocks (events) cannot be distinguished as in your example, and for a time the blockchain is in an inconsistent state.

They are just using existing difficulties in decentralized time synchronization to introduce their Proof of History, which I understand as a centralized time definition based on successive events rather than a decentralized increasing global metric of time if that makes sense.

> Q2: From the paragraph I copied/pasted above, It mentions this:
>
> Because of clock drift and variance in network latencies, the
> timestamp is only accurate within an hour or two.

I'm very surprised by that sentence and would clearly agree with @Mikko Ohtamaa's comment. Computers sync time through NTP regularly and stay relatively close to each other, I'm also pretty sure that the sync frequency is defined so that the average clock drift becomes almost meaningless...

I hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation. Appreciated so much. I will just ask one more thing to confirm my thoughts. So idea is that in Eth, if blocks are mined at the same time, we have many different chains on different nodes and That's what solana calls it a problem, right ? i guess I call it a problem as well, but that's what it is. And we say that solana solves it in a way that when nodes receive blocks, they already know the order in which they came, so blockchain is always in consistent, same state everywhere. Correct ?

Comment: as for the 2nd question, it's really strange they mention 1h or 2h. I mean, ethereum allows 10sec difference, so we are talking about 10sec problem here and not 1 or 2h which doesn't make much sense. WDYT ?

Comment: btw, address is wrong on your about page ! two `0x` appear there :)

Comment: wow nice catch >< thanks for pointing it out :) 

For your first question : I wouldn't say "many" different chains on different nodes, a fork is usually 2 possibilities to two candidate chains, technically you may have forks with 3 or more candidate but the probability is very low. Solana can fork, they don't solve that issue, they solve the time synchronization in the network trough PoH and VDF given some compromises on security and decentralization allowing for very quick ordering and provable ordering of events, which pure timestamps don't allow.

Comment: For your second question : as I said, I think that @Mikko Ohtamaa is right. This 1 or 2h bound is far too great imo... 

Now take what I tell you about Solana with a grain of Salt, i'm mostly focusing on Ethereum for now and didn't spend nearly as much time on Solana. You will easily find  much more knowledgeable people than me on that subject. I'll get the occasion to dive deeper into it later on, I'll edit my answer if needed.

Comment: You mention that: ```Solana can fork, they don't solve that issue, they solve the time synchronization in the network trough PoH and VDF given some compromises on security and decentralization allowing for very quick ordering and provable ordering of events, which pure timestamps don't allow```.

Comment: If node receives blocks in an ordered way, why can there be forks then ? since that node knows the order, other node that receives the blocks would also order it the same way, resulting in the same blockchain. Maybe what you're referring to Solana fork is what if `blockA` gets propated to other nodes and `blockB` doesn't. This way, we have a fork. but if there was no network latency ever, then solana would have no fork..

Comment: Forking in solana is explained here : https://docs.solana.com/cluster/fork-generation
Forks will not happen the same way as in PoW, there is only one leader at a time in Solana while it's a fully open competition in PoW. A malicious or faulty leader can still induce a fork on its own (and possibly be punished for it). My point is that Solana is not immune to forks, they just don't happen in the same conditions because the consensus scheme is different.